# Powershell command to get the driver details of specific driver

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

Is there a powershell command(s) that would allow me to pull the File version from the Driver File Details page of the Device manager?

[image]

What I've tried but has not worked:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_SystemDriver 
Does not show Matrox or a driver version
```

---

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -like '*Matrox*' } | select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion  
DeviceName                    Manufacturer         DriverVersion
----------                    ------------         -------------
Matrox G200eh3 (HPE) WDDM 2.0 Matrox Graphics Inc. 4.5.0.5
```

---

```
Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All 
Does not show Matrox or a driver version that matches 9.15.1.248
```

Comment: Does `Get-PnPEntity -Class MONITOR -PresentOnly |Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_SystemDriver |Select Caption,PathName` show the expected drivers paths?

Comment: For Win10 command looks like `Get-PnpDevice -Class Display -Status OK | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName CIM_DataFile`. And the pulled driver version has the same value with command `Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All |  Where-Object {$_.ClassName -eq "Display" -and $_.ProviderName -like "Matrox*"}`